# pytest cannot find package when I put tests in a separate directory

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a very basic example of a Python package and a test which I'm trying to run with pytest

```
package
 \--
   __init__.py
   spam.py
   spam_test.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty, `spam.py` defines a single function `func()` and `spam_test.py` is:

```
import package.spam

def test_func():
    assert(package.spam.func() == 5)
```

In the root directory I run `py.test` and it all works, returning one passing test.

I *thought* that I could also structure things in this way:

```
package
 \--
   __init__.py
   spam.py
tests
 \--
   spam_test.py
```

But now when I run `py.test` in the root I get:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.0, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: C:\Users\MattUser\Documents\m_drive\notebooks\testing, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________________ ERROR collecting tests/spam_test.py _____________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\MattUser\Documents\m_drive\not
ebooks\testing\tests\spam_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests\spam_test.py:1: in 
    import package.spam
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.19 seconds ===========================
```

I've tried various things to no luck.  What am I doing wrong??

Comment: I was having problems getting some simple tests working and didn't realize they had to be named `test_foo` and not `foo_test`, unlike the filenames...

Answer (score 28):

Well, I got it working.  Add an empty `__init__.py` file in the `tests` directory.

Why does this work?  From the [official docs](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-package-name):

> determine `basedir`: this is the first “upward” (towards the root) directory not containing an `__init__.py`.

So with `tests` *not* containing `__init__.py`, pytest determines that to be the `basedir`.  Adding `__init__.py` forces pytest to recurse up to the root, from whence it can import what it needs to...

Comment: Is it really the recommended way to do this?  Or it's just a side effect?

Comment: This is intentional behavior, See pytest docs, https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/pythonpath.html#test-modules-conftest-py-files-inside-packages

Comment: i have an `__init.py__` and yet still see the OP behavior.

Comment: Adding `__init.py__` did not resolve the issue