# Usual pytest workflow - can't run tests in a file

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to setup a project (Python 3.4.4, pytest 3.3.1) to use pytest, but pytest is failing to run tests in a file or a directory. I think I'm using pytest wrong, but am not what the correct workflow would be.

#### What I've tried

Following the suggestions in ["Good Integration Practices"](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) and also due to the personal preference of having the source and the tests in separate folders, I have setup my project as follows:

```
parent_directory/
    setup.py
    src/
        project_name/
            __init__.py    # empty
            utils.py
    tests/
        __init__.py        # empty
        project_name/
            __init__.py    # empty
            test_utils.py  # has `import project_name.utils.py`
```

With this exact setup, ["Usage and Invocations"](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html) says I should be able to run the tests
using

```
python -m pytest
```

and that pytest will add the current directory to `sys.path` ("*except that calling via python will also add the current directory to sys.path.*"). If I try to do that from `parent_directory/src`, no tests are collected (`collected 0 items`). If I do that from `parent_directory/`, I get `ImportError: No module named 'project_name'`.

After [some reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34520971/746453) -- (see "Test root path"), I have found out that adding (an empty) `conftest.py` to `src/` "*will have pytest recognizing your application modules without specifying PYTHONPATH*".

After doing this, I can go to `parent_directory/` and successfully run

```
pytest
```

and

```
pytest -k test_some_specific_test_function_name
```

Notice that I could switch from `python -m pytest` to just `pytest`, which I'm happy about.

However, if I try to run tests in a specific file (or directory), e.g.

```
pytest tests/project_name/test_utils.py
```

I, once again, get `ImportError: No module named 'project_name'`. This behavior is quite surprising to me.

I have checked:

- [pytest cannot find package when I put tests in a separate directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724305/pytest-cannot-find-package-when-i-put-tests-in-a-separate-directory) - different dir structure
- [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada) (first suggestion is the `sys.path` "hack", second is an environment variable, which is not practical if one works on multiple projects simultaneously -- surely there's a better way)
- [Py.test No module named *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985157/py-test-no-module-named) - different dir structure

#### Question

What would be the correct workflow that would allow me to preserve my directory structure while, ideally from `parent_directory/`, being able to call all of:

```
pytest
pytest -k test_some_specific_test_function_name
pytest tests/project_name/test_utils.py
```

without some manual `sys.path` hacking.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pytest **will** add the current directory to `sys.path`, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it makes your package importable from the source tree. In fact, the entire point of using a `src` and `test` layout is to **prevent** pytest from testing against the source tree.

You can check this yourself by running a python interpreter from the top-level directory of your project and attempting to import the package. It won't work, unless it has already been installed in your working environment.

By using the `src` and `test` layout, pytest is forced to test against an installed version of your package. See [this great blog post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure) with motivation for structuring your project this way. Here's the key paragraph:

> You will be forced to test the installed code (e.g.: by installing in a virtualenv). This will ensure that the deployed code works (it's packaged correctly) - otherwise your tests will fail. Early. Before you can publish a broken distribution.

So if you want to use this kind of layout for your project, you need to install your package before testing. There are advantages and disadvantages to either approach, but pytest recommends it and I'm inclined to agree.

**[update]**

As a workaround for convenient local testing, you can install your package in [development mode](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=development%20mode#development-mode) using either `setup.py develop` or `pip install -e .`. This makes your package appear to be installed in your environment, but any updates in your source tree will be immediately reflected in the "installed" version.<sup>1</sup>

If you choose to follow this approach, you should make sure that you are using a sandboxed development environment (e.g. `virtualenv` or `conda`) so that you don't pollute your system environment.

---

<sup>1</sup> You should be aware that if your package provides and C/C++ or Cython extensions, they will need to be rebuilt manually.

Comment: It seems I inadvertently chose a layout that works better for libraries, not applications. Right now, I expect to be able to run tests locally (all, one, a dir/file), during development, without installing/deploying the app every time (+ on a CI server). I have one fixed configuration the app runs on. 1) What kind of a layout would work well? 2) what is the usual solution if I want to both run quick tests without install AND have a post-install test suite? If you could (even very briefly) extend your answer, I'd be very grateful. Good insight, read the link and a few more, thanks, appreciated!